# WMPLib WindowsMediaplayer.settings.balance doesn't do anything

Tags: c#, winforms, wmplib

I'm trying to set the balance of my WindowsMediaPlayer (WindowsMediaPlayer Player) with a slider (ColorSlider PanSlider) like this:

```
Player.settings.balance = PanSlider.Value;
```

And litterally, nothing happens 'balance-wise.' The sound stays perfectly centered. I've checked and they both output the expected values (-100 ... 100).

Also, `Player.settings.isAvailable["balance"]` returns true.

Any ideas?

Comment: As it turns out, AxWindowsMediaPlayer har no problem dealing with this, however, the mere thought of the process of rewriting all code that breaks if I change from WMP to AWMP does not appeal to me so the question stands.

Comment: I was going to put a bounty on this question, but then I got really bored late last night and I rewrote the program to utilize AxWindowsMediaPlayer instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use :

```cs
Player.settings.balance = (int)PanSlider.Value;
```

Comment: I don't think your answer actually addresses the question. Have you verified that it works?